# Regular expression for Zero value or null value

Tags: regex

can someone tell me the regular expression which will
check if value is 0.0 or 00.00 and that it is a positive value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

`/^0*(\.0+)$?/`

```
0        -> true
.0       -> true
.000     -> true
.001     -> false
.01      -> false
1.0000   -> false
0.000000 -> true
1.1100   -> false
```

***Note:** this regex assumes there are no constructs like `+0.00`; if you need something like that, use this: `/^\+?0*(\.0+)$?/`*. Also, if you ask me, you should the `parseFloat(str) === 0.0` equivalent for your language.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^\+?0+(\.0+)?$/
```

should do the trick.

(I know 0's can't be positive or negative, but I feel it's good to check for a positive sign just in case)

Answer (score 0):

This will match exactly 0.0 and 00.00 as requested. But it's a good idea to check on an undefined amount of zero's as described in other answers.

```
/^0{1,2}\.0{1,2}$/
```

Comment: Good thing there's an infinite amount of ways to express 0, eh? :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't really say this is any better than what's already presented, but it's a  different approach:

```
 $r = "^[^-0.]"
 "0.0" -notmatch $r
 "00.00" -notmatch $r
 "-1" -notmatch $r
 "1" -notmatch $r

 True
 True
 True
 False
```